# Trying find a way to copy down my formula in google spreadsheet without triggering the 3 row differences

Tags: google-sheets

so i have this google form for a tournament and people can sign up alone or until group of 6, i have connected the form to my spreadsheet and i want the "sheet1" (which pool the info from the "answers" that contain the sign up people do in my google form.

so i want the spreadsheet to look like this, and i manage to crate a furmola and fill up all the missing info if there is (in different cases which i need to pull the info from answers sheets depend on how many people registered)

[image of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtU7V.png)

my problem should be really simple compere to the rest but i cant find a way:
each player has 3 rows and up to 7 columns.

C7-8-9 contain the info of the one who registered
but inside them are different address:

```
C7: =Answers!B2
C8: =Answers!C2
C9: =Answers!D2
```

now the idea is to copy down the 3 rows
and that they will keep the letter (B,C,D) but will go up by 1 each 3 raw (profile) so C10-11-12 would be =Answers!B3, =Answers!C3 , =Answers!D3 .
but when i copy down its goes up by 3, cuz of the raw,

so when i select those first 3 rows to copy down the formula it goes up by 3
from 2 to 5, then 7, 9 etc etc
i want it to go by 1 only, as a explained before.

cant find a good way to make it cuz if not i need to change the number in a raw each raw manually, and thats goes take millions of hours as i got lots of answers from my form.

how i can bypass that?

Comment: Why not create a helper column (you could hide it afterwards). Put the relevant 'formula row number' in the relevant rows of the helper column, and refer to the row with your `=Answers!` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Use column A as a "helper column".

In it, on each line, put the row number that applies in the "Answers" sheet. Once you have entered the rows, and the formula are working OK, you can hide the row numbers by changing the font colour to white.

Then use the `indirect` function to refer to the row number variable.
For example, C10: `=Indirect("Answers!B"&A10)`.

This screenshot shows what I mean, and then below is a sample of the "Answers" sheet.

---

**Main sheet**

### [image]

**Answers sheet**
[image]

---

**UPDATE** - Copying helper rows down multiple columns
Lets assume that the helper row values are three sets of 2, three sets of 3, and three sets of 4 (222-333-444). These need to be copied down the helper column for several thousand rows.

The trick is to set the initial value, and make all the other values refer to the initial value. This before "BEFORE" screen shot shows the relationships.
The key point here is the value in the first cell is `=2` (note, not `2`, but `=2`). Each of following 11 cells refer to the first cell.

---

[image: BEFORE]

---

To copy this down as many rows as you may wish, highlight the range of 12 cells, then click and drag the blue range holder down the column. The result is shown in this screenshot.

### [image: AFTER]

Comment: ok thats work and its a better way to then editing the formula each time, but now what happen -> as u wrote i need to type 222-333-444 how can i do it fast and not manually to 2000 rows?

Comment: @waltoBC No problem. Refer the `Update` in my answer.

Comment: hoo i mean i need 222-333-444-555-666... till 2000

Comment: Instead of highlighting 222-333-444 and dragging to copy down; just highlight 333-444 and drag down. The result is 555-666-777 all the way to 2000-2000-2000 and beyond.

Comment: its makes me have 9.1 9.2

Comment: its doesn't give me complete numbers, it break it down to 9.x and after a few rows its get messy with sometimes giving me 4 of the same number when i need only 3

Comment: OK, let's recap. We're taking about the helper column "A", yes?. There is something wrong in your formulas, please double check the formulas in cells A10 to A15 ; they should read **exactly** as follows (refer screenshot) (A10: `=A9+1`; A11: `=A10`; A12: `=A11`; A13: `=A12+1`, A14: `=A13`; A15: = `A14`). Then highlight the range `A10:A15` (six cells, 333-444), click on the little blue box in the bottom right corner of the range, and drag straight down in Column A. It is impossible to get values such as 9.x, etc.